# why am I getting a runtime error by importing react-chartjs-2

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs-2

I'm new to React.  I'm trying to use charjs as a react component.

as soon as I add the following import statement, I get a runtime error:

```
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
```

runtime error:

[image]

The component compiles and causes the above error?

component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';

const BarChart = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            Bar Chart
        </div>
    )
}

export default BarChart
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of `'react-chartjs-2'` are you using?

Comment: Also, do you have `chart.js` installed? @afshin

Comment: chart.js@3.0.2          

react-chartjs-2@2.11.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue.  chart.js was just upgraded from version 2.x to 3.x - there are several breaking changes that react-chartjs-2 is not yet updated with.
I downgraded chart.js version to 2.9.4 and got it to work:

```
 npm install chart.js@2.9.4
```

Comment: Was gonna recommend that. Glad you figured it out anyways